# ReactJS Output won't render to HTML, but works in console log

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a search box that updates this.state.chebi_results with a JSON object onSubmit(). Everything seems to work, except when I try to render the output to HTML. I'm trying to render my output as an unordered list. My Console Log displays exactly what I want. Why is the HTML not being updated?

```
  chebiResults=()=>{
    return(
      <div className='search_results'>
        <ul>
        {this.state.chebi_results.forEach((element)=>{
          <li>{element.name}</li>
          console.log(element.name)
        })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className='ontology_tool'>
      <div className='wraper'>
        <div className='search'>
          <div className='search_tool'>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSearch}>
              <input type="text" name="query" value={this.state.form_query} onChange={this.setQuery}/>
              <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
          </div>
          {this.chebiResults()}
        </div>
        <div className='selected'>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array#forEach` doesn't return anything. Replace you function with `Array#map`.

```
this.state.chebi_results.map((element) => { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `map` not `forEach`.

```
  chebiResults=()=>{
    return(
      <div className='search_results'>
        <ul>
        {this.state.chebi_results.map((element)=>{
          console.log(element.name);
          return <li>{element.name}</li>;
        })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems like my issue was I did not have return before my HTML tags. I did not know you need to have a return within a return. Now it works with both Map & ForEach. Given that both work, why is map preferred over forEach?